# Why can't I connect to External Servers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I want to go on the Lifeboat Survival Games server. It worked the first time I tried it. But then I had to leave.

The next and all the other tries later, it didn't work. It did not say it was unable to connect, it just didn't load and had a Cancel button which is unusual.

I am playing on Minecraft PE. Why won't it load?

Comment: do any other servers load? If you're using PE, are you connecting through the same Wifi? sometimes Free wifi hotspots will block certain ports, like the ones used for Minecraft

Comment: Yes. I am connecting through the same Wifi. None of the other External Servers load but my Worlds do. But my sister can use External Servers and she uses the same Wifi as me.